# JSON.stringify large object optimization

Tags: node.js, json, string, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'd like to convert a large JSON object to string using the `JSON.stringify`, but due to the size of the object I got an error of

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[20817:0x2cc2830]   295727 ms: Scavenge 1335.8 (1423.9) -> 1335.6 (1427.9) MB, 7.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.255, current mu = 0.170) allocation failure 
[20817:0x2cc2830]   295966 ms: Mark-sweep 1339.5 (1427.9) -> 1339.3 (1422.9) MB, 227.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.272, current mu = 0.291) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[20817:0x2cc2830]   295990 ms: Scavenge 1343.2 (1422.9) -> 1343.0 (1426.9) MB, 9.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.272, current mu = 0.291) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x16f9b389e549 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=0x16f9b38877f9 <Object map = 0x39fb09082ba1>,0x1da31d6826f1 <undefined>,0x2762ba9be041 <JSFunction replacer (sfi = 0x1bc744b67dc9)>,0x1deddcf2e701 <Object map = 0x6bcf8da0341>,0x16f9b38877f9 <Object map = 0x39fb09082ba1>)

    1: stringify [0x16c685254241] [/home/blingga/Documents/integrations/integration-flow17employment-hrplus-to-datalake/dist/flow17em...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8c02c0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8c030c  [node]
 3: 0xad15de v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xad1814 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xebe752  [node]
 6: 0xebe858 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]
 7: 0xeca982 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xecb2b4 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xecdf21 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xe962a5  [node]
11: 0xe9dc0b v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
12: 0x11cd6b0 v8::internal::IncrementalStringBuilder::Extend() [node]
13: 0xf92c20 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
14: 0xf9719d v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
15: 0xf977ee v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeArrayLikeSlow(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>, unsigned int, unsigned int) [node]
16: 0xf93e96 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
17: 0xf9719d v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
18: 0xf977ee v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeArrayLikeSlow(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>, unsigned int, unsigned int) [node]
19: 0xf93e96 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
20: 0xf9719d v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
21: 0xf97ef9 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Stringify(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
22: 0xba0051 v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
23: 0x2639339dc17d 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Is there any way I can optimize the `JSON.stringify`? Or is there anyway I can convert my JSON to string? Thanks.

Comment: can u provide a minimal example of payload?

Comment: Hmm... the total size of my JSON is around 500mb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try [`big-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json)?

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const json = require('big-json');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('big.json');
const parseStream = json.createParseStream();

parseStream.on('data', function(pojo) {
    // => receive reconstructed POJO
});

readStream.pipe(parseStream);
```

Comment: Hmm, not yet. Looks promising. I'll try this one.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to try [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream). It let's you stringify or parse a JSON virtually of any size.

Here's a parse example from their docs:

```
var request = require('request')
, JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
, es = require('event-stream')

request({url: 'http://isaacs.couchone.com/registry/_all_docs'})
.pipe(JSONStream.parse('rows.*'))
.pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
  console.error(data)
  return data
}))
```