# Optimize mapping an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 125k test cases and it takes 1 min and 30 secs before I could get the result. Is there any option to optimize my mapping? Thank you..

```
 const getEachValueByLine = () => {
    if (IsJsonString(multipleValue)) {
      setInvalidFormat(true)
      isValidRegex ? setValidRegex(true) : setValidRegex(false)
      const parseValue = Object.entries(JSON.parse(multipleValue))
      const addId = parseValue.map((item, index) => ({ id: index, case: item[0], expected: item[1] }))
      handleMultiValidate(addId)
    } else {
      setInvalidFormat(false)
    }
  }
```

The problem starts in here:

```
const parseValue = Object.entries(JSON.parse(multipleValue))
const addId = parseValue.map((item, index) => ({ id: index, case: item[0], expected: item[1] }))
```

Comment: This link will solve your problem.
Use this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55468857/9928916)

Answer (score 0):

did you try [`big-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json)?

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const json = require('big-json');
 
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('big.json');
const parseStream = json.createParseStream();
 
parseStream.on('data', function(pojo) {
    // => receive reconstructed POJO
});
 
readStream.pipe(parseStream);
```

Comment: how to use this? do I just need to put the `getEachValueByLine` code to the `receive reconstructed POJO`?

Comment: `parseStream.on(multipleValue, function(pojo) {
      // your code
});`

use  like this