# Read json file more than 70 MB size

Tags: json, react-native

Actually, I download the json file with more than 10,000 records from the server and extract the file. But I can not read the json file and convert the data to an object and save it in Realm. I do a lot of searching on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/) and found below modules : [bfi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj) [big-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json) [json stringify large object optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55468777/json-stringify-large-object-optimization) But none of them not work for me in React Native. Invalid fs.createReadStream()

```
 const filepath = "./Basket.json";
 const fs = require("fs");
 var s = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
```

error is : fs.createReadStream is not a function

other way :

```
const bfj = require("bfj");
const filepath = "./Basket.json";
const stream = await RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(
    "./Basket.json",
    "base64",
    4095
  );
console.log(stream);
var b = await bfj.parse(stream);
```

error : Invalid stream argument

Comment: please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If this is not possible, show part of the code and the error message.

Comment: it seems to me that these are syntax errors and are not related to the file's size. does your code work when it's a small sized json file?

Comment: I do not know, Because I could not use function fs.createReadStream() and I get error.
but RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream() is work.